# Python 3.7 spaCy Help Needed- Environment Inconsistency Issue?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spacy, murmurhash

I am facing an issue when trying to call spaCy into my Jupyter notebook. When I run
`import spacy` I get the below:
[image]

I have used spaCy before many times with no issue, but I noticed this problem began after I was trying to also install `from neuralcoref import Coref` and am not sure if that has caused this.

When I go into the terminal and run `conda list spacy` it looks like spaCy is available:
[image]

I do not really understand what the errors are suggesting, but I tried to reinstall murmurhash using `conda install -c anaconda murmurhash` after which I got this. This is just a screenshot of the first few but there are MANY packages that are allegedly causing the inconsistency:

[image]

Following the list of packages causing inconsistencies, I get this:
[image]

For reference, I am using MacOS and python 3.7. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spacy>=3.0` and `neuralcoref` are currently not compatible - the Cython API of spaCy's v3 has changed too much. This might be causing conflicts in your environment?

Comment: Interesting...`neuralcoref` does not even appear when I run `conda list` or `pip list`. I uninstalled and reinstalled `spacy` using `conda install -c conda-forge spacy` from the spaCy documentation, after which I see `spaCy 3.0.5` and `spaCy legacy 3.0.2` in `conda list`. However when I proceed to next step, `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`, I again get ImportError: cannot import name 'hash_unicode' from 'murmurhash'

Comment: I mentioned this because you said "this problem began after I was trying to also install from neuralcoref import Coref". Between v2 and v3 of spaCy, quite a bit of the Cython classes have changed. It is possible than an attempt to install `neuralcoref` installed/referenced some older v2 stuff that is not properly being cleaned up by a reinstall. Is it an option to try again from a clean environment (and stay clear of neuralcoref) to check whether you'd run into the same issue?

Comment: @SofieLV Yep, thats what I ended up doing, and things seem to work now, thank you for letting me know of the incompatibility of my version of `spaCy` and `neuralcoref`. Steering clear of neuralcoref for the time being!